# How to make "two-way binding" Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, components, vue-component

I have child component which function is to upload a photo. Uploaded photo assigned to child component data named "photo".
I need to bind parent data named "file" with child data named "photo". And when "photo" is changed  "file" should be changed too.

Child component:

```js
<template>
  <div class="select">
    <img v-if="previewFile" :src="previewFile" alt="" />
    <img v-else src="/images/empty.jpg" alt="" />
    <label class="btn" for="image-upload">{{ btnLabel }}</label>
    <input id="image-upload" type="file" ref="file" @change="uploadFile" />
  </div>
</template>

import { mapGetters } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "SelectPhoto",

  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
      previewFile: null,
    };
  },
  
  methods: {
    uploadFile() {
      this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
    }
  }
}
```

Parent component:

```js
<template>
    <SelectPhoto :btn-label="text.RU.photoSelect.choosePhoto" v-model:file.sync="file"/>
    <BaseButton :label="text.RU.photoSelect.knowName" @do="$emit('getResult', file, previewFile)" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      file: null,
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already used `$emit` on your `BaseButton` component. You could also use it for `this.file`. In your child component like this:

```
uploadFile() {
    this.file = this.$refs.file.files[0];
    this.$emit('sendMyFile', this.file)
}
```

In you parent component, to react to the action:

```
    <SelectPhoto @sendMyFile="getMyFile" :btn-label="text.RU.photoSelect.choosePhoto" v-model:file.sync="file"/>
```

Also in the parent component do what you want with the `the.file`:

```
methods: {
    getMyFile(file) {
      // do something
    }
}
```